# unable to get multiple table data from sqlite

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have three tables in my database I want to display record from all the tables but it gives the same data in all the rows but i have entered different data in all the tables. Here is the code. when ever I am displaying the data it gives the same record which i entered in last table. I want to call random data from each table. Result gives the single data as I use `Random() limit 1`. but not gives from all the tables. 
It gives the same data as i entered in third row. I want to fetch single record form all the three tables.

```
package com.pawanigroup.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;




public class ViewPeople extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView Starter;
    private TextView MainCource;
    private TextView Dessert;
    private static final String SELECT_SQL= "SELECT * FROM Starter,MainCourse,Dessert ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1";

    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    private Cursor c;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_people);
        openDatabase();
        Typeface myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "myFont.ttf");
        Starter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Starter);
        MainCource =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.MainCourse);
        Dessert = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Dessert);
       Starter.setTypeface(myTypeface);
        MainCource.setTypeface(myTypeface);
        MainCource.setTypeface(myTypeface);



        c = db.rawQuery(SELECT_SQL, null);
        c.moveToFirst();

        showRecords();
    }

    protected void openDatabase() {
        db = openOrCreateDatabase("PersonDB", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    }

    protected void showRecords() {
        String Starter = c.getString(1);
        String MainCourse = c.getString(1);
        String Desstert = c.getString(1);
        //Starter.setText(Starter);
        MainCource.setText(MainCourse);
        Dessert.setText(Desstert);



        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT S.*, M.*, D.* FROM Starter as S,MainCourse as M ,Dessert as D ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1
```

Comment: not working it gives the same record in all the table

Answer (score 0):

You should read more about how the cursors work.

```
c.moveToFirst();// with this you go to the first position, but you don't ever move it in your  showRecords();
```

In your case I would do something like this

```
showRecords(Cursor c){
  if(c!=null && c.moveToFirst()){
    String Starter = c.getString(1);
    c.moveToNext()
    String MainCourse = c.getString(1);
    c.moveToNext()
    String Desstert = c.getString(1);
  }
}
```

Be aware that this might crash if you have insufficient data on your cursor.

Usually the way to go is to iterate over the cursor in a loop. Something like this

```
if(c!=null && c.moveToFirst()){
  do{
      //get data from cursor and do stuff here
      Log.i("Cursor_data",c.getString(1));
  }while(c.moveToNext());
}
```

Comment: it says , or ) is expected

Comment: getting error android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 requested, with a size of 1

Comment: It gives you that error because you only have one value in your cursor. I hope you didn't use the LIMIT 1, from the other answer because that means that you only want one answer and that's what the cursor will contain.

Comment: Ah sorry. It was from you the limit. Don't use that. Also see my updated answer with the loop. You should use that to iterate over the cursor and see what it contains.